# Is it possible to create custom Linux-based Docker image on Azure Windows Server DSVM

Tags: azure-devtest-labs, azure-dsvm

I am using an Azure DSVM in a DevTest Lab running Windows Server 2019. I am trying to get Docker installed and working to allow me to run local experiments from Azure ML Service environments.

I want to build a custom Linux container on Docker - which I believe is possible on Windows from reading some other online posts (I can't use a Linux host for various reasons). When I try to create such an image that contains a `WORKDIR ...` step, I get a "container ***** encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call" error.

I installed Docker on the DSVM (which is a Standard D2s_v3) by adding the "Docker" artifact at creation and then running the following commands to enable Linux containers:

```
$> Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
$> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LCOW_SUPPORTED", "1", "Machine")
```

Running a simple Linux container works fine:

```
$> docker run --rm -it alpine:latest
/ # ls
bin    dev    etc    home   lib    media  mnt    opt    proc   root   run    sbin   srv    sys    tmp    usr    var
/ #
```

To build a custom image, I'm using a simple Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /abm
```

The image appears to `build` successfully:

```
$> docker build --no-cache -t abm-alpine:workdir -f .\abm-alpine.Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> a187dde48cd2
Step 2/2 : WORKDIR /abm
 ---> 495f8ecb3a0e
Removing intermediate container 219e91296e47
Successfully built 495f8ecb3a0e
Successfully tagged abm-alpine:workdir
```

When I `run` the image, I get the following error:

```
$> docker run --rm -it abm-alpine:workdir
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 01fad57c971d672d91238a6c6ec21376e033006ec4c26563e91e7288cfb3bfeb encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106) extra info: {"CommandArgs":["/bin/sh"],"WorkingDirectory":"/abm","Environment":{"HOSTNAME":"01fad57c971d","PATH":"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","TERM":"xterm"},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[50,120],"OCISpecification":{"ociVersion":"1.0.0","process":{"terminal":true,"consoleSize":{"height":50,"width":120},"user":{"uid":0,"gid":0},"args":["/bin/sh"],"env":["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","HOSTNAME=01fad57c971d","TERM=xterm"],"cwd":"/abm","capabilities":{"bounding":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"effective":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"inheritable":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"permitted":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"]}},"root":{"path":"rootfs"},"hostname":"01fad57c971d","mounts":[{"destination":"/proc","type":"proc","source":"proc","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev","type":"tmpfs","source":"tmpfs","options":["nosuid","strictatime","mode=755","size=65536k"]},{"destination":"/dev/pts","type":"devpts","source":"devpts","options":["nosuid","noexec","newinstance","ptmxmode=0666","mode=0620","gid=5"]},{"destination":"/sys","type":"sysfs","source":"sysfs","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev","ro"]},{"destination":"/sys/fs/cgroup","type":"cgroup","source":"cgroup","options":["ro","nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev/mqueue","type":"mqueue","source":"mqueue","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev/shm","type":"tmpfs","source":"shm","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev","mode=1777"]}],"linux":{"resources":{"devices":[{"allow":false,"access":"rwm"},{"allow":true,"type":"c","major":1,"minor":5,"access":"rwm"},{"allow":true,"type":"c","major":1,"minor":3,"access":"rwm"},{"allow":true,"type":"c","major":1,"minor":9,"access":"rwm"},{"allow":true,"type":"c","major":1,"minor":8,"access":"rwm"},{"allow":true,"type":"c","major":5,"minor":0,"access":"rwm"},{"allow":true,"type":"c","major":5,"minor":1,"access":"rwm"},{"allow":false,"type":"c","major":10,"minor":229,"access":"rwm"}]},"namespaces":[{"type":"mount"},{"type":"network"},{"type":"uts"},{"type":"pid"},{"type":"ipc"}],"maskedPaths":["/proc/kcore","/proc/latency_stats","/proc/timer_list","/proc/timer_stats","/proc/sched_debug"],"readonlyPaths":["/proc/asound","/proc/bus","/proc/fs","/proc/irq","/proc/sys","/proc/sysrq-trigger"]},"windows":{"layerFolders":["C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\lcow\\5ba6a7b4fbdf9748ec89898be9bdaa911ee614436a475945638ab296b1155966","C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\lcow\\01fad57c971d672d91238a6c6ec21376e033006ec4c26563e91e7288cfb3bfeb"],"hyperv":{},"network":{"endpointList":["D615E3D5-B6AA-401E-A0A0-72581FA47059"],"allowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}}}}.
```

I've tried various logs (e.g. `Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Compute-Operational` and `Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Docker`) but cannot see any additional information about the error.

Can anyone advise if it is possible to create custom Linux-based images on a Windows DSVM? If it is, can anyone advise what the problem may be or any additional troubleshooting steps I could take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create Linux container on Windows Server.

Although this is currently in experimental stage.

This article might help : https://www.b2-4ac.com/lcow-linux-containers-on-windows-server/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.